# How to position the profile pictures straightly?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to make Facebook like profile picture. I just learned about the CSS grid and wanted to apply it here. Everything is fine except the profile picture line. The bottom lines of the profile pictures does not follow a particular horizontal line. What have I done wrong?

[Enter the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOGP9.png)

Feel free to judge me. I am just a beginner. Thanks a tonne in advance <3. A virtual hug for ya >_*

Here are my codes of HTML(body part) and CSS:

```
<body>
    <div class="layout">
        <div class="profile">
            <img src="../cat-1.jpg" class="profile-picture">
            <div class="profile-name">
                Oliver
            </div>
            <div class="profile-details">
                <div class="mutual-friends-bar">
                    <img class="mutual-friend" src="../dog-1.jpg">
                    <div class="no-mutual-friends">
                        2 mutual friends
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="add-friend">
                    <button>
                        Add Friend
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="profile">
            <img src="../cat-2.jpg" class="profile-picture">
            <div class="profile-name">
                Mimi
            </div>
            <div class="profile-details">
                <div class="mutual-friends-bar">
                    <img class="mutual-friend" src="../dog-1.jpg">
                    <div class="no-mutual-friends">
                        3 mutual friends
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="add-friend">
                    <button>
                        Add Friend
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="profile">
            <img src="../dog-2.jpg" class="profile-picture">
            <div class="profile-name">
                Rex
            </div>
            <div class="profile-details">
                <div class="mutual-friends-bar">
                    <img class="mutual-friend" src="../dog-1.jpg">
                    <div class="no-mutual-friends">
                        2 mutual friends
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="add-friend">
                    <button>
                        Add Friend
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

 
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: Arial;
}

.profile {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin-bottom: 7px;
}

.profile-name {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.profile-name:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: underline;
}


.mutual-friends-bar {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: center;
}

.profile-details {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:29px 29px;
  row-gap: 7px;
}

.mutual-friend {
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.no-mutual-friends {
  font-size: 13px;
  color: rgb(92, 92, 92);
}
.no-mutual-friends:hover{
  text-decoration: underline;
  cursor: pointer;
}

button {
  background-color: rgb(93, 105, 112);
  color: white;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
button:hover{
  cursor: pointer;
}

.layout {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  column-gap: 18px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the `align-items` to `end` in order to align the picture with the text next to it so they both will be at the end of their parent.

```css
.mutual-friends-bar {
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25px 1fr;
  column-gap: 10px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: end;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir <3
I think I wasn't successfully able to share my problem precisely due to my poor English, but yeah, I found a way. I used **align-items: end;** in the layout section and it worked!
Thanks again!